# Skype hangs since upgrading to Mavericks

Tags: macos, skype

Since upgrading to Mavericks the latest version of the Skype app (6.9 rev 701) hangs frequently, pretty much every time on wake after the laptop goes to sleep.

I've heard some suggestions about downgrading to an earlier version in the 6 series, any decent workaround for this problem?

Comment: Here are the related discussions on Skype forums: http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/Skype-issues-on-Mavericks-OSX-10-9/td-p/2045773

Comment: hehe, thanks, seems there are no good options except to wait for a fix, this post pretty much sums it up http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/Skype-issues-on-Mavericks-OSX-10-9/m-p/2058075/highlight/true#M60429

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth upgrading as significant changes have been made for anyone in this situation.